# Is there a way to track a Cosmos DB change history

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way you can track the change history on a Cosmos DB. From what I am aware, when a change is carried out on the Cosmos DB the previous version is lost.

Looking for a way where you are able to revert back as quick as possible if an issue was to occur. There is the obvious option of copying the document which is stored within the Cosmos DB. But it would be good to see a version history / change history on the Cosmos DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosmos DB has a native Changefeed option, which publishes revisions to every document. By consuming the Changefeed, you can see what is changing. However, it would be up to you to decide what to do with those changes, should you have to revert.

Since no "revision histories" are actually stored within a document (aside from the separate Changefeed stream), you'd need to implement something on your own, such as preserving original documents as-is and creating new versions of documents as they change.